# delete ndarray numpy row if it has wrong data type

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have this huge 5 million * 42 ndarray I load from a CSV file. After I do some processing and try to save it into another CSV file with type `float`.

I get the following error:

```
np.savetxt("inputFiles/fixed_X_"+self.file_name, X.astype(np.float), delimiter=",", fmt="%10.0f")
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

I'd like to delete any row that contains this value that cannot be converted into a float (I believe it is a blank cell in the csv file) but I can't locate it due to the huge file size (I can't even open it with excel).

Comment: Format source code and error message properly and provide a *full traceback*

Comment: You might have to use `csv.writer()` and just loop through the array manually.

Comment: Apologies for making an answer, but can't comment yet. Couldnt you have a try in your code? Maybe something like: try: newcellval = float(oldcellval.get()) except ValueError: # Delete the line causing trouble return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy arrays don't hold multiple data types. I'm assuming that in this case, you have an array of type str or type object.

If you know the cells you want to delete are blank, you could get an array with those rows removed with the following:

```
X[ all(X != '',axis=1) ].astype(float)
```

Essentially, giving an index of a list of True/False values will give you a view with only the True rows. This is much faster than actually deleting the rows. You can put any test you want in place of X != ''.

A `X !=` or `X =` test is probably one of the fastest ways you can do this, as everything would be done internally in numpy. However, it's limited in what you can do.

If you actually want to check whether each item can be converted to a float, the following will work:

```
def canbefloat(x):
    try:
        float(x)
    except:
        return False
    else:
        return True
ucanbefloat = np.frompyfunc( canbefloat, 1, 1 )
X[ all( ucanbefloat(X.astype(object)), axis=1 ).astype(bool) ].astype(float)
```

This, however, is around three times slower.

Comment: Thanks man !! the second approach worked !! .. slow .. but it will be done only once !